# API issues and is there a way to make them make sense

Tags: javascript, rapidapi

Ive been trying to understand API's (to be able to make a simple dashboard), as a concept because the how just bemuses me. I wrote some code, and have had some corrections added by a far smarter person who actually knws what they are doing but....I dont understand them at all

I'm just flummoxed by what any of this means and I feel like the dumbest person in the entire universe, and frankly, I am out of ideas so I'm throwing myself at the mercy of stack overflow and hoping I can just get a pointer. I don't expect any one to just do it for me, I just need guidance from a different angle than what I'm getting.

Maybe I'm just doing this so wrong, I need to nuke it from orbit and start again? Maybe.

```
const newsMount = document.getElementById(`news-mount`);
newsMount.innerHTML = `<div class="spinner-border text-primary" role="status">
<span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
</div>`;

const newsAPI_key = `03e2495c94587b3792e617e2c72ebe96`;

//url

/********* YOU DIDN'T ADD THIS VARIABLE (and it's query, not news city) ******** */
const query = "ukraine";

const newsEndpoint = `https://gnews.io/api/v4/search?q=${query}&token=${newsAPI_key}`;

// TRY to use async/await. (You'll need to be in a script loaded with type="module" or an IIFE with the async keyword before the function keyword)

try {
  const response = await fetch(newsEndpoint);
  if (!response.ok) throw response;
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(":rocket: ~ file: main.js ~ line 83 ~ data", data);
  renderNews(data.articles); // send the right bit of the data on
} catch (err) {
  console.log(":rocket: ~ file: main.js ~ line 86 ~ err", err);
  // deal with error
}

function renderNews(articles) {
  console.log(":rocket: ~ file: main.js ~ line 91 ~ renderNews ~ articles", articles);

  // loop over the data and append
  for (const article of articles) {
    const {
      title,
      content,
      // main: { headline },
    } = article;

    // You'd want to do this with a documentFragment, rather than keep adding HTML to the DOM multiple times...
    newsMount.innerHTML += `
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h2 class="card-title">${title}</h2>
        <p>${content}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
`;
  }
}

// sports

const leagues = "leagues";

const sportsName = document.getElementById(`sports-mount`);
sportsName.innerHTML = `<div class="spinner-border text-primary" role="status">
<span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
</div>`;

// You used a normal string instead of a template string here...

const sportsEndpoint = `https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v3/q=${leagues}?id=39`;

const options = {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "7720ed5535mshd73c681a1e70e9cp10f92djsn180d9fb",
  },
};

// response says that "You're not subscribed to this API" - so you'll need to check your settings in your rapidapi.com dashboard

try {
  const response = await fetch(sportsEndpoint, options);
  if (!response.ok) throw response;
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(":rocket: ~ file: main.js ~ line 83 ~ data", data);
  renderNews(data.articles); // send the right bit of the data on
} catch (err) {
  console.log(":rocket: ~ file: main.js ~ line 141 ~ err", err);

  // deal with error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, don't feel bad, everyone starts small. But i think it could help you to use the [request library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request). It makes things a bit easier.

Also you could watch a YouTube guide for the basic understanding of an API.
[Try this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s7wmiS2mSXY)

Comment: Tahnks for the kind words. API's really just...I cannot get them to work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're that far off, and the comments aren't all helpful IMO (they're not incorrect at all - some are just totally irrelevant the issues you're having).

First, as an approach it's best to do one thing at a time, get it working (and git commit if there's any chance at all you might break it and not understand why) and only then add to it.

For example, get the fetch working without any DOM (getElement etc), or get the DOM working without the fetch. And of course, only try to implement one API call before implementing two.

And for your question itself, it needs more focus. Is there a specific line of code, non-working functionality or comment you don't understand?

Comment: I had a chat with a person who was trying to help me out, tbh im still confused but we move etc. Thanks for rresponding, its kind of you to do so.